# How many colors does it take?

Tags: graph-theory, polyomino

This question is from a popular monthly science magazine in my country:

You have an 8x8 square where any 3 squares forming a [tromino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tromino) (including reflections and rotations) must consist of three different colored squares. At least how many colors do you need to paint the entire board?

**Bonus:** How about larger boards?

Comment: Re: the edits, I was sure that the right name was triomino (based on tri(o)-), but I had put the word "popular" right before "science" because I wanted to stress that the magazine deals with *popular science*, so I don't think it necessarily breaks the adjective order rule.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the answer is

> 5

using the following coloring:

> [image: 8x8 board]

For other board sizes,

> 5 is sufficient as well; the pattern can just be repeated. (Of course, a 2x2 board needs only 4 colors because there are only 4 squares. And does 1x1 even count as a board?)

Reasoning:

> Consider a square not on the edge of the board with its 4 orthogonal neighbours; they all have to have different colors since each pair is part of a tromino. Therefore, we need at least 5 different colors; the pattern shows 5 is sufficient.

Comment: I think it's wrong, the angular triomino "2 5 3" (with the 5 at the angle) is repeating. The 2 on first line, 2nd column, and the 2 on 4th line 3rd column, they make the same triomino with the same colours.

Comment: They are all repeating (since it's a pattern); the point is that each triomino has three different colours. Triominos are not compared with each other (at least that's how I interpreted the puzzle).

Comment: Oh, i thought that each triomino must have had a unique colour pattern, even after a rotation or an inversion

Comment: That might be an interesting new puzzle...

Comment: Not that it was a particularly difficult puzzle, but you work fast.

Comment: I cant find an answer for 9x9.

Comment: @Oray what's wrong with just extending the pattern?

Comment: @Glorfindel ok I got it thanks :)

Comment: If at all possible, it's good to use something else than [different shades of red and green](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6542/upvote-downvote-arrow-colors-cant-be-easily-differentiated-when-color-blind) for conveying significant information.

Comment: Yeah, good idea.

Comment: should a 2x2 board not only need 3 colors?

Comment: Eh ... no, it definitely needs 4.